# Different numpy version in Anaconda and numpy.__version__ in IPython Shell

Tags: python, numpy

I used [How do I check which version of NumPy I'm using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520234/how-do-i-check-which-version-of-numpy-im-using) to learn how to get the version of numpy. However, when I run `conda list | grep numpy`, I get:

```
numpy                     1.15.2           py36ha559c80_0
numpy-base                1.15.2           py36h8128ebf_0
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py36_0
```

However, when I run version from IPython shell, I get:

```
import numpy as np
np.__version__
Out: '1.13.3'
np.version.version
Out: '1.13.3'
np.version.full_version
Out: '1.13.3'
```

Why are the two versions different? Which one should I trust? Thanks for any help.

---

Please note that I am not using `venv` (i.e. virtual environment). I am directly accessing Anaconda's packages. So, there is no issue about versioning.

---

Here's what PyCharm is showing me:
[image]

---

As per [Conda's version information on package doesn't correspond to __version__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51553668/condas-version-information-on-package-doesnt-correspond-to-version), here's `__file__` and `sys.path`. Please note that I have hidden my name for privacy issues.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have besides your `python 3` environment in `anaconda`, another `python` with `IPython` and `numpy` installed.

It looks like that PyCharm and Anaconda see (correctly) the same `numpy` versions, while `IPython` which, I assume you didn't start from within your anaconda environment, sees another `python` installation with the older `numpy`. In fact, your output shows, that there is another `python3.6` in `C:\Users\...` which doesn't belong to `anaconda`.

To make `numpy 1.15` available in `IPython` you can either start `IPython` from within your anaconda environment by typing in the terminal (easier solution)

```
C:\>activate <your_anaconda_environment_name>
(<your_anaconda_environment_name>) C:\>ipython
```

or you make your local `IPython` load the modules from the `anaconda` environment by having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386048/ipython-reads-wrong-python-version). This will be not a recommended option in this case, given the resulting cross linkings of two python installations.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that PyCharm reads older python version from location `App-data\roaming...` What I did is that in start-up script, I added the following code.

```
print("Correcting sys paths now...")
paths = [
'C:\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Anaconda3',
 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
]
import sys
for path in reversed(paths):
    sys.path.insert(0,path)
print("Completed correcting sys paths now...")
del path
del paths
```

Above code will force Python to read latest files from Anaconda. However, if you are using virtual environment, you would need to point to that environment.

If you want to know where is Python installed, you can run:

```
import os
import sys
os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

---

Above answer is inspired from [conda python isn't using the numpy version I try install if I also specify that it should use python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597201/conda-python-isnt-using-the-numpy-version-i-try-install-if-i-also-specify-that?rq=1). It doesn't provide the solution. I have posted a solution above.